# error al utilizar fetch en window

Tags: javascript, windows, fetch, formdata

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNsAV.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola a todos como ven me sale un error y no se como solucionarlo, solo envio mi url absoluta al fetch y luego paso el formData intente solucionarlo con este codigo de aqui abajo pero no resulta... estoy utilizando ese codigo dentro de una funcion async

```js
const res = await fetch(self.url, {
    method: 'POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': location.origin,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: formData
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta:

- Estás haciendo un fetch a un backend `https` desde un frontend `http`. Eso cuenta como un request cross-domain, y tu backend no está configurado para ese tipo de peticiones.

Usa https en tu front o modifica tu llamado para pedir http al backend.

**Respuesta larga:**

Además de hacer el request entre protocolos distintos, veo otros dos parámetros mal puestos y uno que puede llevar a errores.

**1.- Header "allow-origin" como atributo**

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': location.origin,
```

No es un atributo del llamado Fetch. Es un header, pero tampoco tiene sentido hacer:

```
headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': location.origin
}
```

Porque es un header de respuesta. **Tiene que enviarlo el receptor** del llamado a un request de tipo OPTIONS para señalar que acepta el envío CORS. (no necesitas enviar el OPTIONS, el preflight lo hace el browser cuando haces tu request igual que ahora)

**2.- Inclusión de credenciales**

```
credentials: 'same-origin'
```

Si el destino está en tu mismo host, entonces ese es el comportamiento por defecto. Se enviarán tus credenciales (en la forma de cookies) junto con el llamado. Si fuera un request cors, entonces tendría que usar `credentials: 'include'` lo cual sólo funcionará si el backend devuelve el header  `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

**3.- Content-Type explícito** (posible problema, improbable)

Si tu content type  es `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` no es necesario declararlo. Sin embargo en tu pregunta dice que el body es `formData`. ¿Estás instanciando un objeto `formData` tú mismo? Posiblemente el content-type debiera ser `multipart/form-data`.

En general cuando sea [un safe-type](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header) ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data", "text/plain") puedes omitirlo porque sin importar lo que pongas manda el mimetype que detecte el backend. Sí es importante declararlo, en cambio, si fuera JSON, dado que hay una diferencia entre enviar `application/json` (unsafe) vs enviar un request json que constituye [una excepción](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-exceptions) a la norma. No es tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

No es problema de tu javascript, sino del backend https://spd.test/backend/index.php por la extensión de la URL asumo que estas trabajando con PHP, en tu script debes agregar esto al principio:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Esto se hace porque hay una medida de seguridad que no permiten que se realicen peticiones asíncronas de un dominio a otro y con ese código das permiso.

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, el problema es [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), puedes cambiar tu backend y agregar el header
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` sin embargo, eso haría un poquito más vulnerable tu sitio web a ataques [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) y otros exploits que justamente CORS busca limitar.

En este caso, te propongo la solución de usar rutas relativas si las rutas a las que harás la petición son las de tu propio sitio o bien, estandarizar todo a ya sea `http` o a `https` (de preferencia a `https`) pues me parece que el error surge porque desde `http://sdp.test` estás haciendo una petición a `https://sdp.test` (son diferentes). El código para realizar la petición me parece que es correcto solo sería cambiar la variable `self.url` a cualquiera de los 2 valores:

- `http://sdp.test/backend/index.php`
- `/backend/index.php` (que al final terminará siendo la opción de arriba si la petición se origina desde `http://sdp.test` como es el caso de la imagen)

Espero haberte ayudado.